# save image of d3heatmap in a file

Tags: r, d3.js

I am using d3heatmap package in R for to draw heatmaps. When I use it in Rstudio, I can save images that it produces by choosing save image from the viewer menu. I am wondering how I can save the heatmap to a file in an Rscript. Apparently, png(filename) does not work.

Comment: If you can get phantomjs installed, take a look at `widgetThumbnail` - https://github.com/tesseradata/trelliscope/blob/master/R/thumb.R - (bad name, it's a full image, but i assume the use of the word thumbnail was meant to imply static vs dynamic). You should be able to copy the necessary code into your R session (or load that pkg or mine - https://github.com/hrbrmstr/streamgraph/) and call the function from there.

Comment: Good question, It seems that `png(filename)` `plot()` `dev.off()` does not work, neither does `x<-recordPlot()` & `replayPlot(x)`

Answer (score 5):

A potential approach is using [htmlwidgets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/htmlwidgets.pdf) and save it in html form only since the d3heatmap returns object of class "d3heatmap" "htmlwidget"

EG.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
data(mtcars)
map <- d3heatmap(mtcars, scale = "column")
saveWidget(map, "test.html")
```